# Errno 10055 cannot connect in Python network related code on Windows

Tags: python, windows, networking

I am new to creating networks, and relatively new to python.  I recently purchased a second computer to run some python programs.  That second computer enters data into a mysql database housed on my main computer.

I am getting a lot of 10055 errors.  Sometimes from selenium/urllib, sometimes from trying to connect to the mysql database.  The errors either provide:

Selenium - Errno 10055. An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

MySQL - Can't connect to MySQL server on IP (10055)

I have searched for hours for a solution to this problem, but cant find one that works.  Any ideas?

I am running windows 7, on a pretty powerful computer.  I really doubt this is a memory problem.

one of the pieces of code that is causing problems is the following (I am getting the can't connect to mysql server) - it only gives problems sometimes:

```
    def connect_to_database(schema_name):
             import MySQLdb
             import socket
             counter = 0
    #try 100 times until a connection is made
             while counter <= 100:
                    try:
    #gets ip of host comp
                            ip = socket.gethostbyname('PC NAME')
                            conn = MySQLdb.connect(ip, "username", "pw", schema_name)
                            c = conn.cursor()
                            conn.set_character_set('utf8')
                            c.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
                            c.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
                            c.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
                            break
                    except Exception, err:
                            print traceback.format_exc()
                            try:
   #if failure, use different ip, so far i have only seen 2 ip's for the network.
                                    if socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) == '10.0.0.13':
                                            ip = '10.0.0.14'
                                    else:
                                            ip = '10.0.0.13'
                                    conn = MySQLdb.connect(ip, "username", "pw", schema_name)
                                    c = conn.cursor()
                                    conn.set_character_set('utf8')
                                    c.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
                                    c.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
                                    c.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
                                    break
                            except Exception, err:
                                    print traceback.format_exc()
                                    counter = counter + 1
            return c, conn
```

Comment: We may need some code

Comment: "...pretty powerful computer. I really doubt this is a memory problem" -- Don't underestimate your capability to bring any mighty machine to its knees via bugs.  `def foo(): os.fork() ; foo()`, e.g.

Comment: There is an awful lot of code, and the errors are coming up in different spots on the new computer.  These errors don't show up when I run the same programs on the main computer.  The main computer is substantially less powerful than the first (2ghz, 8gb) v. second (3.4ghz i7 16 gb).

Comment: Is there something with ports that I am missing that I must do to properly configure my new computer to do what I want it to do?

Comment: I would run the code, and then - based on the errors - show the relevant code. It is *ok* to split up a complex issue into several smaller questions. That way it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution.  More testing will confirm.  I increased the number of empheral ports on my windows7 machine to 65,000.  See below for instructions.

[how to change/view ephemeral port range in windows machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006939/how-to-change-view-ephemeral-port-range-in-windows-machines)