# GemFire with GFSH - Region creation with server start throws BindException

Tags: java, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire, geode

I am trying to create a GemFire cache and region at the time of starting a cache server using GFSH command.

GFSH:

```
gfsh start server --name=server1 --server-port=40405 --classpath=$CLASSPATH   --cache-xml=/tmp/gemfire/8.2.7/config/cache.xml  --locators=hostA[10334],hostB[10334] --mcast-port=0
```

Cache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache http://schema.pivotal.io/gemfire/cache/cache-8.1.xsd" version="8.1" lock-lease="120" lock-timeout="60" search-timeout="300" is-server="false" copy-on-read="false">
 <pdx>
    <pdx-serializer>
      <class-name>
       com.gemstone.gemfire.pdx.ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer
      </class-name>
    <parameter name="classes">
      <string>com.gemfire.DomainObjects</string>
    </parameter>
  </pdx-serializer>
 </pdx>
<region name="Customer" refid="REPLICATE"></region>
</cache>
```

When I run the gfsh command, I am getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Failed to create server socket on  null[40,405]
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.SocketCreator.createServerSocket(SocketCreator.java:828)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.SocketCreator.createServerSocket(SocketCreator.java:758)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.tier.sockets.AcceptorImpl.<init>(AcceptorImpl.java:466)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.BridgeServerImpl.start(BridgeServerImpl.java:342)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheCreation.create(CacheCreation.java:607)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.SocketCreator.createServerSocket(SocketCreator.java:825)
        ... 15 more
```

Any help?

I used netstat to find if the port is occupied. I couldnt find any and i executed the script still i am getting same exception.

```
bash-4.1$ netstat | grep 40405
bash-4.1$ ./startServer.sh 
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................The Cache Server process terminated unexpectedly with exit status 1. Please refer to the log file in /var/tmp/sn17180/gemfire/8.2.7/config/server1 for full details.

[severe 2018/05/06 04:37:53.156 IST  libgemfire.so nid=0x17921700] SIGQUIT received, dumping threads  
java.io.EOFException: Locator at hostB(server1:18877)<v73>:10334 did not respond. This is normal if the locator was shutdown. If it wasn't check its log for exceptions.
        at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.tcpserver.TcpClient.requestToServer(TcpClient.java:125)
        at com.gemstone.org.jgroups.stack.tcpserver.TcpClient.requestToServer(TcpClient.java:78)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.ClusterConfigurationLoader.requestConfigurationFromLocators(ClusterConfigurationLoader.java:171)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.requestAndApplySharedConfiguration(GemFireCacheImpl.java:874)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.init(GemFireCacheImpl.java:1025)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.create(GemFireCacheImpl.java:688)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:182)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:229)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.startWithGemFireApi(ServerLauncher.java:793)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:695)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.run(ServerLauncher.java:625)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:195)
Exception in thread "main" com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireIOException: While starting bridge server  CacheServer on port=40405 client subscription config policy=none client subscription config capacity=1 client subscription config overflow directory=.
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheCreation.create(CacheCreation.java:611)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.xmlcache.CacheXmlParser.create(CacheXmlParser.java:340)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.loadCacheXml(GemFireCacheImpl.java:4269)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.initializeDeclarativeCache(GemFireCacheImpl.java:1184)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.init(GemFireCacheImpl.java:1026)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.GemFireCacheImpl.create(GemFireCacheImpl.java:688)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:182)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.CacheFactory.create(CacheFactory.java:229)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.startWithGemFireApi(ServerLauncher.java:793)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.start(ServerLauncher.java:695)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.run(ServerLauncher.java:625)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.distributed.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:195)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Failed to create server socket on  null[40,405]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BindException: Address already in use even with unique port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329580/bindexception-address-already-in-use-even-with-unique-port)

Comment: No. this is different. This issue is common across any frameworks we use. But as far as gemfire is concerned, I am a beginner and i am not sure if i am doing things right.Thats why i have posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means some other process running on localhost is already bound and listening to client socket connections on port **40405**.  Perhaps you have another GemFire Server already running on that port?

In which case, you need to vary the port numbers for as many servers as you start, for example...

```
gfsh> start server --name=One --server-port=40405 ...
...
gfsh> start server --name=Two --server-port=40406 ...
...
gfsh> start server --name=Three --server-port=40407 ...
...
```

... and so and so forth.

If a non-GemFire process is already running using that port number than either considering killing that process or using another port for your GemFire `CacheServers`.

You can use the Linux `netstat` command to find which process is using the port and act appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is this the right way of creating cache and region while starting up the server?. Can you please suggest a tutorial for using cache.xml (to create cache and regions) with gfsh server start and then have another Java process to load the regions created. I am finding it hard to find such resource.

Comment: I have updated the post with netstat. I find the port is free. But i have got no clue why this issue is coming.

Comment: I have got it fixed. I killed PIDs and tried but it didnt work. Then i removed all server and locator directories, then re-executed the steps which worked. Do these directories create issue?. Should we clear the directories before server restart?

Comment: It's possible that you had some duplication causing two instances of the server to be started.

Comment: If your clients are connecting through locator(s), you can also specify an ephemeral port for the server (`--server-port=0`). That way the server will pick some random open port. Clients will discover the correct port when they initially connect to the locator. Note the option is `--server-port` and not `--port` as indicated above. `--port` is used to set the port when starting a locator.

Comment: Right, my bad.  Thanks Jens.  It is `--server-port` option in the `start-server` _Gfsh_ command to affect the `CacheServer` port.  The `--port` affects the p2p port used to communicate amongst (peers, or `CacheServers`) forming a cluster.