# DatagramSocket.Receive without port set

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I've recently started to learn about socket usage, more specifically in Java.

In [this link](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/) is shown a simple client-server UDP application.

My question is: How does the client receives the response with receive() method when this datagramsocket object calling receive doesn't have a port set?

Comment: AFAIK, either the DatagramSocket or the receive method must provide a port but at least one must do so. I suggest you ask the author whether this should work or not.

Comment: But when this is the case, how does the client datagramsocket knows that the incoming packet belongs to him?

Comment: It doesn't which is why I suspect it wouldn't work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Could you give me a little help? :x I'm doing a java program using a udp client-server. When I set the client datagramsocket to the same port as the server I get a "java.net.BindException: Address already in use". However, when I don't set the client port, the server packet never reaches the client :c

Comment: @CodeCamper Thanks for the invitation! But i'm in a bit of a hurry (college assignment), so i'm afraid i wouldn't have time for it :\

Comment: @TiagoSchoepingReinert if your client and server are running on the same machine you have to use different ports for each. You get that bind exception because both the client and the server are  on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client initializes its `DatagramSocket` via the nullary constructor, which binds the socket to some available port (chosen in an unspecified manner) on the wildcard address.  That's quite different from not having a port set -- there *is* a port set, but it is chosen by the computer, not explicitly specified by the program.

When the server receives a message, it extracts not only the message data, but also the source address and port.  It sends its response to that address and port.  The client successfully receives it via the same socket with which it sent the original message, because it's still bound to the same port, even if you don't know exactly which one that is.

Comment: Are you sure you are not thinking of TCP client-server?  With UDP, it doesn't have a connection and will only listen to a fixed port.

Comment: Oh, thinking about it now, it does really makes sense. Thank you this answer!

Comment: @PeterLawrey I fixed my code by using your answer! I changed my server-side datagramPacket and now it's working. The destination port set previously was a static one (32000). Now i'm using the received packet port (from the client) and works! Thanks :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey, no, I am not thinking of TCP (which also listens only to a fixed port).  The question is which port (if any) the client listens to.  Per [its docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#DatagramSocket%28%29), the nullary constructor of `java.net.DatagramSocket` does bind it to a local port; it's simply a port of the system's choosing instead of the programmer's.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How does the client send a message to the server if he does not know the port the server is hosting on in the first place?

Comment: @JohnBollinger both of you are correct! My question originally was regarding  datagramsocket without user defining a port. However, Peter Lawrey helped me fix the error in my code! Thank you both :)

Comment: @CodeCamper in the example on the link I posted, the server side port was defined, just the client one wasn't. When the client sent a datagramPacket to the server, the server was able to discover the client port by using DatagramPacket.getPort(), and then sending the packet to the client through it!

Comment: It is called an ephemeral port.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck, *I* know that, but the meaning of that term is not necessarily clear to a person such as the OP, who seems to have limited experience with network programming.

Answer (score 0):

the first time you send a packet using that socket, an ephemeral port will be allocated. If you need a specific port then you can bind it explicitly which is needed for bootp for instance. But in the most simple case bind is not needed and you get the ephemeral port.

The peer will see this port in the UDP header because in there is both the source and destination port.

As a side note this mechanism is the same for TCP clients. When they do a call to `connect()` unless the socket was bind to a specific port, an ephemeral port will be allocated by the clients kernel and that one will be used for the lifetime of the connection.

The ephemeral ports are usually in a specific range, there is kindof a pool of ports for UDP and TCP. The kernel usually has a mechanism to take from the pool starting from the beginning and gradually incrementing till the end is reached upon which he'll start from the beginning. Skipping ports that are still in use of course. It is called the ephemeral port range, and it is specific to the os.

[how to change/view ephemeral port range in windows machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006939/how-to-change-view-ephemeral-port-range-in-windows-machines)