# Winsock2: Using connect() to connect to server, but from tcp port < 1024?

Tags: winapi, winsock, winsock2

Does Winsock2 have an API to define which TCP port a client uses to `connect()` to a server?

We need to `connect()` to a UNIX server, which only responds if the client TCP port is `< 1024` (Reserved ports, which are accessible only to UNIX user "root", are in the range 1 to 1023. Non-reserved are in the range 1024 to 65535, read [Port Usage](https://www.beyondtrust.com/docs/privilege-management/unix-linux/admin/settings/port-usage.htm)).

If we use the plain Winsock2 API, we get a random TCP port number, and if it is above 1023, the server will not respond.

Comment: I can understand a server not being able to listen on a reserved port unless it's running with admin/root access, but I've never heard of a server refusing to accept clients that are connecting from reserved ports.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `bind()` the client socket to the desired local IP/port before `connect()`'ing it to the server.

Comment: So how can someone find out which ports are available? Looping over bind() is not an option, depending on security settings it can take 1-2 seconds per bind().

Comment: Does Windows not have an API for bind() to select a free port <= 1023 for bind()?

Comment: @CedricBlancher "*how can someone find out which ports are available?*" - you can't, as there is no API to query that (although, it is possible to query the ports that are in use, but that doesn't mean unused ports are usable). And even if you could, it would cause a [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) to do so. "*Looping over bind() is not an option*" - unfortunately, it is your only option, if you want to hunt for a free port.  Best to let the OS just pick one for you, and then you can use `getsockname()` to discover which one was chosen.

Comment: @CedricBlancher "*Does Windows not have an API for bind() to select a free port <= 1023 for bind()?*" - if you `bind()` to port 0, then the OS will select an available ephemeral port for you. But there is no guarantee that the port will be `<= 1024`, in fact it likely won't be since [Windows ephemeral ports are usually `> 1024`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/default-dynamic-port-range-tcpip-chang) unless [configured otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006939/). So, if you must use a port `<= 1024` then you must `bind()` in a loop, sorry.